# PHP is displaying my source code?

Tags: php, command-line, php-5.3

I just upgraded to php5.3 and when I execute:

```
php myfile.php
```

I see the source code for myfile.php.

Any idea why this is happening?  I've never seen anything like it before!

Comment: Executing sounds like he is using the php cli. So there is not server involved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 5.3

```
short_open_tag
```

is disabled by default.  So if you use

```
<? ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php ?>
```

it can cause issues in the future (provided you just re enable the flag in php.ini).  From what I have read they are still debating removal from 6.

Comment: I sure hope they won't remove them from 6. They are so convenient when writing templates.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you didn't forget the opening PHP tag at the begining of the file ?

ie :

```
<?php
echo "hello, world!";
```

*(Note I used "full" open tags ; ie "`<?php`", and not short open tags "`<?`" -- maybe you used short open tags, and those are disabled ? If I remember correctly, they are disabled by default, in PHP 5.3)*

and not :

```
echo "hello, world!";
```

*(If that doesn't help : can you post a short code sample that reproduces the problem ?)*